# TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

My bot has stopped working, here is my code. I want the bot to listen for @snoop across multiple discord servers and respond with snoop when it is gets hears the ping snoop. Its a basic listen and respond

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const start = new Date();
let snoop = 0;

client.on('ready', () => { console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`); });

client.on('ready', msg => {
    if (msg.guild === null || !msg.guild.hasOwnProperty('members') || msg.guild.members === null) { return }

    const role = msg.mentions.roles.first();

    if (typeof role === "undefined") {
        return;
    }

    const member = msg.guild.members.get(client.user.id);
    const channel = msg.channel;

    // user is not role member of channel
    if (!member.roles.has("" + role.id)) {
        return;
    }

    if (msg.content.match(/(snoop)/i)) {
        console.log("snoop detected", role.name, channel.name, channel.id)

        const t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000 - 2500)) + 2500;
        console.debug(`sending snoop to ${channel.name} (${channel.id}) in ${t}ms`)
        channel.startTyping();

        setTimeout(() => {
            channel.send("snoop").then(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    channel.stopTyping();
                }, 100);
            });
        }, t);

        boxes++
        const s = parseInt((new Date()).getTime() - start.getTime()) / (60 * 1000)
        console.info(``)
    }
    }); 
    client.login('apikeyhere')
```

This is the error I am getting:

> typeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
> at ClientDataManager.newChannel (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:81:36)
> at Guild.setup (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js:307:68)
> at new Guild (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js:74:12)
> at ClientDataManager.newGuild (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:26:19)
> at ReadyHandler.handle (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/Ready.js:20:91)
> at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
> at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
> at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/stuart/Downloads/discordbot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
> at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)

When i do node index.js this comes up

Comment: Can you please fix your formatting (code & question) and try to explain what you wanted to to, what your code **should** do and what the result is?

Comment: It's basically listening for a ping across all servers and responding when it hears a certain word.. Sorry about the formatting i am new to all this.

Comment: Next time you should read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question :)

Comment: As i said im new to this site.. I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You are using twice "client.on('ready'".
One are you using to check if the bot started but the other one that you are using shouldn't be 'ready' but 'message'. Your codes are based on a message and not on when the bot started.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. Its working now thank you so much!!